# add segment with jquery for codeigniter url

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, url

I have a codeigniter page with url like

```
 example.com/index.php/test/create
```

I need to add an ID to the url without reloading my page,I was try

```
window.location.href=window.location.href+'/'+my_id;
```

But the page was reloaded.is possible to change my url without reloading my page and add the id as my third segment.After a refresh i need to access that value with

```
$this->uri->segment(3);
```

Comment: you can do it by adding `#id`

Comment: i need to access that segment after refrish with $this->uri->segment(3)

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: I think your question is inherently flawed. CodeIgniter is a php framework, thus it is interpreted on the server. Javascript is a client-side language, so even if you can accomplish changing the URL without refreshing. CodeIgniter will not be made aware of the 'id' until the page is submitted or refreshed.